# How to remove space between Input field and command link on VF page

Tags: visualforce, html, style

On VF page I want to show input field and Command link together how to set those components together ?

Page :

```
<apex:inputField  value="{!object.M__c}" />
             <apex:commandLink  action="{!}" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/86328352/Icon" /> </apex:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing occurred because of the context your code is in (`apex:pageBlockSection`). In order to fix this, you'll need to use an `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputLabel>{!$ObjectType.Object.fields.M__c.Label}</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:inputField  value="{!object.M__c}" />
         <apex:commandLink  action="{!}" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/86328352/Icon" /> </apex:commandLink>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

You'll probably want to make some additional tweaks to the code, as this answer primarily addresses placing multiple elements into a single data column of your `apex:pageBlockSection`.